# Numpy method to split a real number into n-equal parts?

Tags: python, numpy, split

I'm looking for something along the lines of:

```
numpy.split_equal(1.0, 3)
#[0.3333, 0.6666, 1.0]
```

Thanks for all direction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps `numpy.linspace`

```
import numpy as np

def split_into_parts(number, n_parts):
    return np.linspace(0, number, n_parts+1)[1:]
```

Result:

```
>>> split_into_parts(1, 3)
array([ 0.33333333,  0.66666667,  1.        ])
```

Comment: Ah, very much what I was looking for. Thanks a bunch.

Answer (score 5):

You really, *really* do not need numpy for this. Not even a little bit. You can use basic arithmetic:

```
def split_equal(value, parts):
    value = float(value)
    return [i*value/parts for i in range(1,parts+1)]
```

For example:

```
>>> split_equal(1, 3)
[0.3333333333333333, 0.6666666666666666, 1.0]
```

Comment: I appreciate the response. I was looking through the Numpy API and was more curious if there was a predefined method rather than list-comprehensive method. It seems to have plenty for splitting arrays, but not much for real numbers.

Comment: That's because numpy is designed to make it possible/easier to work with huge data sets, hence the focus on arrays. You just don't need a library when working with single numbers.